# Read xlsx file in Rscript from vb

Tags: r, vb6

I've been trying to create a function in vb6 that reads a script in R, and this script reads an xlsx, for a job.

However, when I run the program a black screen appears and it closes, and nothing is generated.
I attach the codes

VB

```
 Dim dir1, dir2 As String
        dir1 = "C:\example"  'example folder route
        dir2 = "C:\example2"  'example folder2 route
        dir1 = Replace(dir1, "\", "/")
        dir2 = Replace(dir2, "\", "/")


        Dim proc = New Process
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\i386\Rscript.exe"
        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\i386"
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\example.R" + " " + dir1 + " " + dir2
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
        proc.Start()
```

Rscript

```
#generate .txt  for test
    library("readxl")
    sink('C:/hello.txt',append=F,type="output")
    cat('Hello World')
    var1<-5^3
    var2<-7^3
    cat('\nThe result of ',var1,'to',var2,'is',var1+var2)

#acept parameters of vb
    args<-commandArgs(trailingOnly=T)
    CD<-as.character(args[1])
    ROOT<-as.character(args[2])

#read excel file
    data2<-read_excel("test.xlsx", sheet = 2)
```

Comment: If you've been trying to write a function in VB6 then why did you post VB.NET code? It's one or the other so you don't need both tags.

Comment: sorry, I thought those of VB.NET too could help me.

Comment: VB.NET and VB6 are very similar but also quite different.  The code you have posted is VB.NET, not VB6.  Please make sure that you know what language you're using and use only relevant tags.

Comment: Its OK to mix up VB6 and VB.net - but you should edit your question to clarify now that this has been brought to light.

Comment: As a first step, I would disentangle the R script issue from the "black screen" issue. #1, figure out if R is even being run / called correctly. Then if it is, you can debug the R side of things. I would verify carefully all strings which hold paths & filenames, and perhaps substitute something else as a test like the path to notepad.exe. You can even temporarily copy notepad.exe (say) to c:\ just to ensure you have a dead simple path (no spaces, minimal chance of typoes, etc.) and use that to confirm your are using the Process object correctly.

Comment: Possibly a good-ole Windows 'run-as' issue. What user identity does the R process get run as when executed from VB? Does that user have rights to execute R? Usually one exe calling another is run as some proxy down-rights user identity such as network service.